# How can i test my website functionality automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, automation

I am developing a website's CMS in laravel. Here i am assigning blog to user manually by following steps:
1. Select a user from the list.
2. Click on assign new blog.
3. Select a blog to assign.
4. Click on assign.

Now i want to test this process on 500 users. Is there any way for test it automatically rather then do 4 steps manually.

Comment: [Laravel dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/dusk) is what you are looking for.

Comment: You probably want to use laravel dusk for browser testing. It will act like a user "navigating through" your website and you can assert tests. These test can be look for text, click buttons to see results, etc. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk